# Disable INFO level logging for Spring boot websocket MessageBroker logs

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have a spring boot application with Websocket enabled wit SockJs. All works nice but it keeps logging below message in the console.

```
2017-09-19 11:04:48.164  INFO 8856 --- [MessageBroker-4] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[1 current WS(1)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 3 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(3)-CONNECTED(3)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 45], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 22], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 4, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 65909]
```

What is the significance of the log and how can I disable only these type of logging?

Comment: you can upgrade log level to ERROR/WARN to disable INFO logs

Comment: I would like the INFO log to be disabled only for this not for others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use following configuration in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.socket.config.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats = ERROR
```

this will upgrade logs for this particular class.

Comment: This will work, but the scheduled task which logs this will still be running in the background. It should be disabled to prevent unnecessary resource usage.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to improve [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46292745/9786749)  based on the comment of @Dino, because it is true that this solution doesn't show the logs but it doesn't disable the task and doesn't prevent unnecessary resource usage.

To prevent unnecessary resource usage use the following implementation:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketLoggingConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        webSocketMessageBrokerStats.setLoggingPeriod(0);
    }

}
```

Now it is not necessary to modify the log level using `application.properties`.